# OpenGeo SDK: Add New Server trouble with proxy/?url=

Tags: boundless-suite

I'm currently developing an application with the OpenGeo SDK.
I wish to have the "Add New Server" functionality and I've followed the example from the documentation: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/sdkintro/viewer/addnewserver.html

In my applications file, I've added proxy: "proxy/?url=" and also * @require overrides/override-ext-ajax.js

When I test the application on my server (e.g., suite-sdk debug path/to/myapp) everything works fine.

However, when I deploy the application (I use a Tomcat container) then the "Add New Server" functionalities doesn't work any more. I've always the following error message when I try to add a WMS: Error getting WMS capabilities (Layer source not available.). Please check the URL and try again.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. In my case it was placing instruction within portalConfig when should be placed within the Viewer. Like this:

```
...
var app = new gxp.Viewer({
    proxy: "proxy/?url=",
    portalConfig: {
        layout: "border",
        region: "center",
...
```